# How to make gitk show only local branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitk

How to make gitk show only local branches? Or even better - can I hide remote branches that do not have corresponding local branches?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some experimenting I have found a solution. The following command works:

```
echo $(git branch) | gitk
```

It shows only those remote branches that have corresponding local branches. It is important to use `echo $(git branch)` since it forces `branch` to return raw list of branches instead of formatted output such as the following:

```
$ git branch
  develop
  release-M4.1
  vendor
* xflow
```

Comment: Try just running `echo $(git branch)`; you should see all the files in your current directory as well, due to the asterisk in the output of git branch.

Comment: I have specifically used echo to hide git's asterisk. I believe git is able to detect when it is being run as part of "echo" or not. It won't print asterisk from within echo.

Comment: This seems to be shell-dependent rather than anything to do with `git`. I see the `*` expanded into file names when I run it in `bash` or `ksh`, but the `*` is left alone when I run it in `zsh`.

Comment: I used bash. Unfortunately I don't the the setup anymore to test it again.

Answer (score 18):

You can create a new "View" that shows only local branches like this:

1. Go to View -> New View... (Or press Shift-F4)
2. In the dialog that appears, give the "View Name" something meaningful like "Local Branches"
3. Check "All (local) Branches" in the References area
4. Check "Remember this view" to save these settings for future launches

Now, you should see a "Local Branches" option in the View menu. Choosing this view will only show commits present in local branches. Note that you may still see remote branch labels, but only if the commit they point to is in a local branch.

Answer (score 9):

Since I found this question in a search, the accepted answer didn't work for me, and I eventually found a solution that did, I figured I'd share:

```
gitk --argscmd='git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads'
```

It will even update if you add a branch and then refresh a running gitk with F5. You can include tags as well with:

```
gitk --argscmd='git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads refs/tags'
```

Or using rev-list (shorter, but slightly cheating):

```
gitk --argscmd='git rev-list --no-walk --branches --tags'
```

Comment: Thanks. Hope it'll be useful to other people who find this question.

Comment: works better on poshgit like this : gitk --argscmd="git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads refs/tags"

Answer (score 2):

`gitk --branches`

It corresponds to going into "view" and checking "All (local) branches"